# R: Compute mean of values for different time horizons

Tags: r

let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(ParameterID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                                    2, 2, 2),
                    Time= c(as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:15:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:20:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:25:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
                            as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00")),
                    value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3))
```

and these settings

```
low_interval <- 30
high_interval <- 15
```

I want to achieve the following. Every `high_interval` minute, in this case 15 min, the mean `value` should be computed over the observation of each Parameter specified by the id. When `ParameterID == 1`, the `high_interval` should be used. That is, the observations of the last 15 minutes should be used for the mean. However, when `ParameterID == 2`, `low_interval` should be used. That is, the observation of the last 30 minutes should be used for the mean.
My starting point is

```
data <- df %>%
  mutate(diff = as.double.difftime(Time - min(Time), units = "mins")) %>%
  mutate(group_low = cut(diff, breaks = seq(0, max(diff)+low_interval, low_interval), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(group_high = cut(diff, breaks = seq(0, max(diff)+high_interval, high_interval), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(group_high)
    # A tibble: 9 × 6
  ParameterID Time                value  diff group_low group_high
        <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     <fct>     
1           1 2022-01-01 10:05:00     1     0 [0,30]    [0,15]    
2           1 2022-01-01 10:10:00     2     5 [0,30]    [0,15]    
3           1 2022-01-01 10:15:00     3    10 [0,30]    [0,15]    
4           1 2022-01-01 10:20:00     4    15 [0,30]    [0,15]    
5           2 2022-01-01 10:05:00     1     0 [0,30]    [0,15]    
6           2 2022-01-01 10:10:00     2     5 [0,30]    [0,15]    
7           1 2022-01-01 10:25:00     5    20 [0,30]    (15,30]   
8           1 2022-01-01 10:30:00     6    25 [0,30]    (15,30]   
9           2 2022-01-01 10:30:00     3    25 [0,30]    (15,30]
```

I could easily group the observations for the same time horizon with `data %>% group_by(ParameterID, group_high) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))`. However, I could not find any way to distinguish between how much we look back depending on each parameter without splitting the dataframe into two parts.

To clarify the question, this is some pseudocode of the goal:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  interval mean_1        mean_2       
  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>        
1 [0,15]   mean(1,2,3,4) mean(1, 2)   
2 (15,30]  mean(5, 6)    mean(1, 2, 3)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you mean the calculated `mean` and not the string as shown. Are you sure that the `mean_2` for `(15,30]` contains three numbers?

Comment: yes correct.  i see your point. indeed, the interval annotation (15, 30] might be a bit misleading for mean_2. Mean_2 should be the mean over 30 minutes over parameter 2.  So in the second group of Parameter 1 (e.g. 15-30), parameter 2 from (0-30) should be used for building mean_2. If we follow this approach, e.g. for parameter 1 in group (45-60), parameter 2 from (30-60) should be used

Comment: But there is only one value of `ParameterID == 1` in the `(15, 30]` interval - this is `3`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think there must be two, namely the observation at 10:25:00 and 10:30:00

Comment: Sorry, I meant for `ParameterID == 2`.

Comment: For this parameter there is one times a `value=1`. But `1`shows up in both groups - the same for `value=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this approach, which takes your code and modifies it further.

As mentioned in the comments there is only on value ( `3`) in `mean_2` for second interval.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- dplyr::tibble(
  ParameterID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  Time = c(
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:15:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:20:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:25:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:05:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:10:00"),
    as.POSIXct("2022-01-01 10:30:00")
  ),
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3)
)

low_interval <- 30
high_interval <- 15

test_df <- df |>
  mutate(diff = as.double.difftime(Time - min(Time), units = "mins")) |>
  mutate(group_low = cut(
    diff,
    breaks = seq(0, max(diff) + low_interval, low_interval),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  )) |>
  mutate(group_high = cut(
    diff,
    breaks = seq(0, max(diff) + high_interval, high_interval),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  )) |>
  group_by(ParameterID, group_high) |>
  mutate(rn = cur_group_id()) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(ParameterID, rn),
    names_glue = "{ParameterID}_{rn}",
    values_from = value
  ) |>
  select(4:8)

test_df |>
  summarise(across(1:4, ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) |>
  pivot_longer(-1) |>
  drop_na() |>
  mutate(name = substring(name, 1, 1)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) |> 
  setNames(c('interval', 'mean_1', 'mean_2'))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   interval mean_1 mean_2
#>   <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 [0,15]      2.5    1.5
#> 2 (15,30]     5.5    3
```